# How to write JUnit test cases for GET API?

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, junit

I have a GET API which accepts different parameters in controller class. According to the boolean parameter, the API should return a different result. How can I write JUnit test cases for the same?

```
@CrossOrigin

@RequestMapping(value = "/api/brand/multi-get", method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes =
        MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE, produces =
        MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)

public ResponseDTO listBrands(@RequestParam(required = false) Integer start,
                              @RequestParam(required = false) Integer limit,
                              @RequestParam(required = false) Boolean show_rejected) {

    ResponseDTO responseDTO = new ResponseDTO();
    System.out.println("------------------");
    try {
        if (start == null) {
            start = 0;
        }
        if (limit == null) {
            limit = 50;
        } else if (1 <= limit && limit <= 250) {
            if (show_rejected) {
                List<Brand> brands = brandService.findAllBrands(start, limit);
                if (brands != null && !brands.isEmpty()) {
                    responseDTO.setData(brands);
                    responseDTO.setCode(ErrorCode.error_0);
                    responseDTO.setMessage("Brand list");
                    return responseDTO;
                } else {
                    responseDTO.setData(new ArrayList<>());
                    responseDTO.setCode(ErrorCode.error_0);
                    responseDTO.setMessage("Brand list");
                    return responseDTO;
                }
            } else {
                Page<Brand> brands = brandService.findAllActiveBrands(start, limit);

                if (brands != null && !brands.isEmpty()) {
                    responseDTO.setData(brands);
                    responseDTO.setCode(ErrorCode.error_0);
                    responseDTO.setMessage("Brand list");
                    return responseDTO;
                } else {
                    responseDTO.setData(new ArrayList<>());
                    responseDTO.setCode(ErrorCode.error_0);
                    responseDTO.setMessage("Brand list");
                    return responseDTO;
                }
            }
        } else {
            responseDTO.setCode(ErrorCode.error_1104);
            responseDTO.setMessage(ErrorCode.error_msg1104);
            return responseDTO;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return responseDTO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring framework and mocking the tests, then the spring-test library contains the `MockMvc` and `MockMvcRequestBuilders`classes, which can be used to test any APIs. You for GET API, you can build a request with 
    `public static MockHttpServletRequestBuilder get(String urlTemplate, Object... uriVars)` method in `MockMvcRequestBuilders`

Then you can use `public ResultActions perform(RequestBuilder requestBuilder)` method in `MockMvc` for hitting the service.

Answer (score 0):

Invoke the GET API and assert for response details.

```
@Test
    public void postSimpleBody() throws Exception {
        Response response = server.newRequest("/path").request().buildPost(Entity.text("42")).invoke();
        assertEquals(Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode(), response.getStatus());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to annotate your tests class with the following annotations:

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
```

If you have authentication add:

```
@WithMockUser
```

Autowire the mockMvc to perform the requests:

```
@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;
```

Use `@MockBean` to mock the service layer:

```
@MockBean
private BrandService brandService;
```

And annotate your test with the `@Test` annotation:

```
@Test
public void test_listBrands_when_something_do_something() {
}
```

Then using [Mockito](https://site.mockito.org/), mock the method in the service covered by your test:

```
List<Brand> mockBrands = new LinkedList<Brand>();
mockBrands.add(new Brand(/*...*/));

Mockito.when(brandService.findAllBrands(0, 25)).thenReturn(mockBrands);
```

Create the requestBuilder using the class `org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders`:

```
MockHttpServletRequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/api/brand/multi-get?start={0}&limit={1}&show_rejected={2}", 0, 25, true)
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
```

Perform the request and assert the results using the class `org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers`:

```
mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder)
    .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
    .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
```

As a final tip, add this 2 static imports so your code will be shorter:

```
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;
```

Then you can do `get()`, `post()`, `status()`, `content()`, etc

Here is the full example:

```
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;

@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class MyApiControllerTests {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private BrandService brandService;

    @Test
    public void test_listBrands_when_something_do_something() {
        //#region Mocks
        List<Brand> mockBrands = new LinkedList<Brand>();
        mockBrands.add(new Brand(/*...*/));

        Mockito.when(brandService.findAllBrands(0, 25)).thenReturn(mockBrands);
        //#endregion

        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder requestBuilder = get("/api/brand/multi-get?start={0}&limit={1}&show_rejected={2}", 0, 25, true).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder)
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

    }

}
```

Comment: Its showing an error on ".andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));" Since it is a GET API ,we should give "APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED" instead of "APPLICATION_JSON" Right? But when I give "APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED" it is showing the same error on   ".andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));"

Comment: The problem is: One I posted above and..

-> First of all I have to write test case for if(show rejected) condition, then only it will enter in to "List<Brand> brands = brandService.findAllBrands(start, limit);". How should I write the test case to test if(show rejected ) condition.

-> How to write test case for the else condition when it returnd a "Page" other than List of Brands.

Comment: `.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` indicates that you expect the api to return a json and then you validate this using `.andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))`

Comment: And sorry I forgot to write an example to show you how to pass parameters to as form url encoded. I will edit the answer

Comment: Done!. Now you can test each path of your code, keep in mind that you should create a method for each test and only mock the service when it is reached by the test